# Jquery +datatables causing CSP errors for inline style

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, content-security-policy

I have been trying to get rid of the unsafe-inline from the CSP style-src headers as it is vulnerable.
While removing this, I am getting below errors in jQuery execution in chrome:

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'nonce-TXYxR0tlamZ1emk2a3Y4RHFwdTdTZ0JaR1R2TTdEaUk=' 'unsafe-eval' ". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-Z0MkpGRk0/9QW+7eJ/G1D//1i6WKVbat+HlIwkiFln4='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution

While debugging I found that it is failing at

> From jquery 3.5.1

```
    tmp.innerHTML = wrap[ 1 ] + jQuery.htmlPrefilter( elem ) + wrap[ 2 ];
```

in buildFragment method.
At failing point ,elem is evaluated as a string which contains the html for tr containing inline style generated by the datatables.Even though the datatables seems to be applying CSP safe way as below but when it gets passed back to jQuery whole TR containing inline style is loaded as innerHTML which gets failed due to unsafe-inline

> from datatables.js 1.10.21

```
_fnApplyToChildren( function(nSizer, i) {
            nSizer.innerHTML = '<div class="dataTables_sizing">'+footerContent[i]+'</div>';
            nSizer.childNodes[0].style.height = "0";
            nSizer.childNodes[0].style.overflow = "hidden";
            nSizer.style.width = footerWidths[i];
        }, footerSrcEls );
    }
```

As seen above datatables is applying inline styles in CSP acceptable way as they are applying style property directly on the elements style property
Below is the run time value that gets evaluated in "elem" in jquery buildFragment method containing inline styles

`<tr role="row"><th class="dataGridCheckBoxCell sorting" aria-controls="tablegrid" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=": activate to sort column ascending" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px; width: 41px;" role="columnheader"><div class="dataTables_sizing" **style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden;"**><div id="checkAllQueues" class="selectable" role="checkbox"></div>`

I am not sure if it is a data tables issue or jquery or combination of both.
Any insight on the issue will be helpful or any workaround that can be applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it's specifics of [jQuery buildFragment](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation/buildFragment.js) DataTables plugin creates "fragments" in a CSP safe way, but after that the `buildFragment` keeps those as HTML string and inserts it as HTML.

jQuery has [htmlPrefilter()](https://www.w3big.com/jquery/misc-jquery-htmlprefilter.html) method to modify all existing jQuery manipulation methods. `buildFragment` uses this method when it wraps stored elements:
`tmp.innerHTML = '<div>' + htmlPrefilter(elem) + '</div>';`

You can to modify this htmlPrefilter() to make  `style='...'` ->  `data-style='...'` within all tags. On document is ready event yo need to select all `data-style` attributes, to parse its content into array and aplly CSP safe `element.style=` to each array's elements.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it not something that needs to be fixed in jQuery?